# How to format a label with a comma delimiter in reverse using JavaFX

Tags: javafx, formatting, label, settext

So basically I want to do the following:

```
   String s1 = "hello";

   for(int count = s1.length() -1; count >= 0; count--){
        System.out.printf("%c, ", s1.charAt(count));
    }
```

but do that in a label instead. How can I format a label like printf? Using setTextf does not woek as seen below:

```
String s1 = "hello";
for(int count = s1.length() -1; count >= 0; count--){
        label1.setTextf("%c, ", s1.charAt(count));
    }
```

Comment: `Label` does not have a `setTextf()` method. A good idea would be to read the official API docs for [Label](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html) so you have a better idea of what you should expect it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `printf()` method is intended specifically for printing a formatted `String` to your output console.

If you want to format a `String` for other purposes, you need to use the `String.format()` method:

```
String s1 = "hello";
for(int count = s1.length() -1; count >= 0; count--){
    label1.setText(String.format("%c, ", s1.charAt(count)));
}
```

---

However, doing this within a loop as you are trying to do will result in a single `char` as your final `Label` text, since each call to `setText()` will overwrite the previous one.

Instead, you should build your final `String` using a `StringBuilder`:

```
String s1 = "hello";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int count = s1.length() -1; count >= 0; count--){
    sb.append(String.format("%c, ", s1.charAt(count)));
}

label1.setText(sb.toString());
```